# Can AWS config send email to resource tag owner email for non-compliant alerts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-config

If I enable ssh-restricted rule in AWSConfig with remediation.

Can I close the ports with auto remediation  and also send a email to the owner of the resource based on the tag information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an AWS Config rule is determined as non compliant you can have [CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html)/[EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/what-is-amazon-eventbridge.html) perform an action such as trigger an SNS topic or invoke a Lambda.

If you have it trigger a [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/), you will receive an event containing the resource(s) that are no longer compliant.

The Lambda function could access these resources tags via the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) which would grant the meta data over whom the email should be sent to. You could then take this information and send an email using a SMTP library to an external service (such as [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/)).

This Lambda could also remediate any issues via the AWS SDK.

Take a look at the [How can I be notified when an AWS resource is non-compliant using AWS Config?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/config-resource-non-compliant/) page for some guidance on setting up the event part of this flow.

Comment: Will this work from centralized  AWS Config?  Do I need to configure lambda functions only in main account?

Comment: So the first thing is you can indeed share CloudWatch events between accounts to centralise them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEvents-CrossAccountEventDelivery.html. From here the SNS and Lambda would remain in that account. To interact with the EC2 API I believe your Lambda would need to assume a role in the account of the EC2 instance and then interact with the API using the temporary credentials. More information on this here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

Comment: Do I need centralized  cloudwatch event ? As AWS config will be centralized  to the main account. Also AWS config can trigger a remediation  action for a non compliant alert, which will trigger lambda or SNS

Comment: Ah in which case no you do not need to worry about centralising that :) If it can trigger the Lambda within then that will also work :)